# how to check if a text cursor is showing

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

how to check if a text cursor is present in a specific HANDLE using Windows API

```
#include <window.h>
int main()
{
 if (text_cursor)
 {
  //do stuff
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would that be useful to know? This reads much like the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) and [`GetGUIThreadInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-guithreadinfo).

```
#include <window.h>

bool isCaretActive(HWND hwnd)
{
    DWORD dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL);

    GUITHREADINFO info = {};
    info.cbSize = sizeof(GUITHREADINFO);
    return GetGUIThreadInfo(dwThreadId, &info) && (info.hwndCaret == hwnd);
}

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = ...;
    if (isCaretActive(hwnd))
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But know that this only works if the HWND is using a system-provided text caret. This will not work if the HWND uses a custom caret, or no caret at all.